# fibonacci c++ gmp generator

Tags: c++, fibonacci, gmp

Hello I am attempting to implement gmp to an existing fibonacci generator I wrote. I have been reading over the gmp documentation but there is still much I do not understand. The original fibonacci generator is here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fib {
  int n; 
  long unsigned int first, second;
public:
  Fib() {
    first = 0;
    second = 1;
    cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "First " << n << " terms of Fibonacci series are:" << endl;
  }

  int solve() {
    int i; 
    long unsigned int next;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n + 1 ; i++) {
      if(i <= 1) {
        next = i;
      }
      else {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
      }
    }
    return next;
  }
};

int main() {
  Fib fib;
  cout << fib.solve() << endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

I installed gmp using:

sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

When I try to implement gmp I did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

class Fib {
  int n; 
  mpz_class first, second;
public:
  Fib() {
    first = 0;
    second = 1;
    cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "First " << n << " terms of Fibonacci series are:" << endl;
  }

  int solve() {
    int i; 
    mpz_class next;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n + 1 ; i++) {
      if(i <= 1) {
        next = i;
      }
      else {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
      }
    }
    return next;
  }
};

int main() {
  Fib fib;
  cout << fib.solve() << endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

I know at some point I need to convert from a int to a string, then clear the output variable or something like that. when I attempt to compile I run:

g++ -lgmpxx -lgmp fib.cpp -o fib

my output:

```
fib.cpp: In member function ‘int Fib::solve()’:
fib.cpp:30:12: error: cannot convert ‘mpz_class {aka __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1],     __mpz_struct [1]>}’ to ‘int’ in return
     return next;
            ^
```

I am a complete noob to bignum libraries, any help would be great. I am reading the documentation but I am struggling with implementing it.

Comment: Please use the C++ interface. You only need to include <gmpxx.h> and replace `unsigned long` with `mpz_class` in your original code.

Comment: By the way, you really need to learn how to read a doc. mpz_init takes a single argument, what do you mean by giving it 2?

Comment: Almost got it I get this output once making the corrections:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/projects/c++/fibonacci_cpp$ g++ -lgmp fib.cpp -o fib
fib.cpp: In member function ‘int Fib::solve()’:
fib.cpp:30:12: error: cannot convert ‘mpz_class {aka __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>}’ to ‘int’ in return
     return next;
            ^
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/projects/c++/fibonacci_cpp$

Comment: Well, you are not returning an int but a mpz_class, so fix the signature of the function...

Comment: I thought from looking over other peoples examples you were supposed to set the value for the init in the second argument. I have been going over 3 different tutorials for it. That is probably part of my problem. Sorry I can not read a doc.

Comment: When you say fix the signature of the function what exactly do you mean? do you mean the data type at the beginning? I tried void and char as well as int but the later two give me even more errors on output.

Comment: I tried void, char, int, mpz_class as signatures but none will compile. Reading through documentation again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, thank you Marc Glisse for pointing me in the right direction!

I simply removed the function return and allowed the function to just return the ouput.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

class Fib {
  int n; 
public:
  Fib() {
    cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "The " << n << "'st Fibonacci number is:" << endl;
  }

  void solve() {
    int i;
    mpz_class first, second, next;
    first = 0;
    second = 1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n + 1 ; i++) {
      if(i <= 1) {
        next = i;
      }
      else {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
      }
    }
    cout << next << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Fib fib;
  fib.solve();
  return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want
3301
First 3301 terms of Fibonacci series are:
    330153163507162264637094778670152653434758914922281728912670042596222213549775330156165336158736310556035302724174567603559968964146698655928480718496410717009709564103992213321320869628734803460669663152332798570186240768164370808688660485835985642189726235311578136722218902035069558368032277843436948382319806290480685283349217035498351102885889468646619750569482644246863804467015344937199892515242806415403581786532923017170033416624774209919795051514102027827396052441847160310846646083321110222356075543424672128051593137886359425865994528848747739182600228659941846983982384323813903695048726976986370288741982958687841091743740983161275336114608885705665822704734020694899622487801
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/projects/c++/fibonacci_cpp$
```

Comment: Uh, that's broken. Doesn't your compiler tell you that you are missing a return statement?

Comment: I changed the int signature to void since its just sending an output stream back. googling -Wall option now